# Spring boot Cannot find template location Debug Mode

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to make boot project.

My issue is my project cannot found templates in Debug Mode

> Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)

But work on BootRun

Another projects are working same settings.

[project tree img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSOgM.png)

- build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

- controller

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

- index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

how can i solve it?
thanks for reading.

[1]:

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'debug mode'? Is that running from your IDE? If so, what IDE are you using?

Comment: I’m using Intellij. Debug mode mean Intellij Debug Mode